# next.js Error with static nested route content (directory) using [...id].js

Tags: next.js

I've been following the tutorial on the site to build out a small application. I am stuck with a catch-all route or a nested route based on the subdirectory structure.

I have all my files as markdown in the `./posts` directory and in `./pages` directory I would like to have subdirectories  (categories) that some posts live in.

```
pages/content/category-1/post1
pages/content/category-2/post2
etc
```

My site is only able to serve content at `pages/content/[id].js`, if I put `[...id].js` as a way to catch-all routes, I get this error:

`Error: A required parameter (id) was not provided as an array in getStaticPaths for /category/[...id]`

If I place `[id].js` in every subdirectory `./pages/content/category-1/[id].js` it works but that is pretty inefficient if I have a ton of category directories.

I am following the tutorial and my `[...id].js` looks like this:

```
import Layout from '../../components/layout'
import { getAllPostIds, getPostData } from '../../lib/posts'
import utilStyles from '../../styles/utils.module.css'
import Head from 'next/head'

export default function Post({ postData }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Head>
        <title>{postData.title}</title>
      </Head>
      <article>
        <h1 className={utilStyles.headingXl}>{postData.title}</h1>
        <div className={utilStyles.lightText}>
        </div>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: postData.contentHtml }} />
      </article>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Return a list of possible value for id
  const paths = getAllPostIds()
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
  }  
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  // Fetch necessary data for the blog post using params.id
  const postData = await getPostData(params.id)
  return {
    props: {
      postData
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try pages/content/[categoryId]/[id].js. Maybe here you can find an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57648690/2-levels-nested-routing-in-nextjs

Comment: Thanks, very similar. I made a directory [categoryId] and place [id].js inside but now when I visit /content/category-name/post I get this error
"Error: A required parameter (categoryId) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /content/[categoryId]/[id]"

Comment: categoryId should be a string as suggested by the error, for some reason it is not. You need to convert it to string.